# How to change Site Title and Description using Sharepoint Web Service?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to read and change the Title of sharepoint site (both SPSite and SPWeb) using Sharepoint web services.

I have the url to the sharepoint site. Wanted to change the title of the page using the sharepoint web service.

Cannot create a SPWeb.

Any input.

Comment: Can you add the entire error message with the stack?

Comment: Thirteen years later you can't still change the title of a site collection. Embarrassing Microsoft!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the current SharePoint webservices have methods for updating a web or site collection's Title. However, you could [write your own webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) that could do this fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the title and description through a web service but don't change it because there's no update method. [Webs.GetWeb Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webs.webs.getweb.aspx)